# How to run an RDD of SQL commands

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an RDD[String] of a whole lot of strings that look like "INSERT INTO hive_metastore.default.redirects VALUES (123,56),(589,32)(267,11)". I'd like to be able to run all of these commands to get the data into my actual table, instead of just having a bunch of strings with instructions to get them into the table. For context, I'm doing this on databricks, and I don't know enough to have set up any odd settings there. (I hope.)

At first I tried just doing `insertIntoLines.foreach{ x => spark.sql(x) }`, but that does not seem to work. That is, code like this:

`val test = sc.parallelize(Array("INSERT INTO hive_metastore.default.svwiki_redirect VALUES (18,0,'Användbarhet','','')","INSERT INTO hive_metastore.default.svwiki_redirect VALUES (25,0,'Apokryferna','','')")).toDS()`

`test.foreach{x => spark.sql(x)}`

gives an error like this:

`error: overloaded method value foreach with alternatives:   (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachFunction[SqlCommand])Unit <and>   (f: SqlCommand => Unit)Unit  cannot be applied to (SqlCommand => org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)`

It does, however, work if I insert a `collect` to get `insertIntoLines.collect().foreach{ x => spark.sql(x) }` - and that is fine for my toy data, but for the actual data, I really don't want to have to fit it all into memory on the driver.

Surely there is a nice and principled way of doing this, that doesn't either bottleneck hard at the driver or involve digging into the SQL commands with bespoke regexes?

Comment: Could you please tell a bit more about the issue you are observing without the `collect` call? Are there any errors in executors' log files?

Comment: Overall, I probably would consider alternative approaches to the problem such as some sort of bulk uploading with pre-processing because it seems like, in your case, the distributed executors would still query a single database behind the metastore. That may be suboptimal in terms of scalability and performance. For example, see the [Optimizing INSERT Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html) page in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: Also, please consider if there are security risks such as [SQL-injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection).

Comment: *a single database or a relatively small number of databases.

Comment: The error I am getting without the collect is: `error: overloaded method value foreach with alternatives:   (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachFunction[SqlCommand])Unit <and>   (f: SqlCommand => Unit)Unit  cannot be applied to (SqlCommand => org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)`

Comment: Someone made an answer that is now deleted that explained something along the lines of the spark session not being present in the right way on the worker machines, and that being the cause of the error. I don't remember the details, unfortunately.

Comment: Regarding alternative approaches: I am getting this data as a text file containing these lines of SQL commands. I am not sure what alternative options there are for processing this that do not run into these issues?

Comment: So, it's a compile-time error. Could you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The answer was mine: probably it's incorrect.

Comment: I have added a two-line example that reproduces this error to the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using Dataset or Dataframe instead of RDDs. ? Thereby you could avoid calling `collect()`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
case class SqlCommand(query:String)

val querySet = Seq(SqlCommand("query1"), SqlCommand("query2")).toDS()
querySet.foreach(query => spark.sql(query.query))
```

NOTE: `spark.sql` command will not work with `foreach` due to the mismatch with return types that foreach expects which is a `Unit` and spark.sql returning a DataFrame/Dataset. So this solution will not work as expected.

Comment: There are two problems with this: 
a) `spark.sql` expects a String, not an SqlCommand, so you need to do `querySet.foreach(query => spark.sql(query.query))`
b) When you do that, you get the following error instead:
``error: overloaded method value foreach with alternatives:
  (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachFunction[SqlCommand])Unit <and>
  (f: SqlCommand => Unit)Unit
 cannot be applied to (SqlCommand => org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)
querySet.foreach(query => spark.sql(query.query))
         ^``

Comment: The error is coming due to the fact that foreach expects a return type `Unit` everytime the function is applied to each of the elements. In this case `spark.sql` returns `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame or Dataset`. 
Another fact is that spark.sql doesn't support insert into commands. So ideally this approach wouldn't work.  It is described [here](https://dwgeek.com/spark-sql-insert-into-table-values-issue-and-alternatives.html/) and you could try the alternatives mentioned.

Comment: I am fairly confident that neither of your analyses of the source of this problem can be correct, since it works perfectly if I collect() the RDD and run the foreach on the driver machine.